# Cual es la diferencia entre JIT y AOT en Angular

Tags: angular

He estado indagando sobre este tema pero aun no encuentro una respuesta clara sobre la diferencia, es decir básicamente entiendo que compilan en distintos momentos y esto mejora la performance en AOT, con esto me basta para usar AOT en las versiones productivas.

Pero que es lo que compila en distintos momentos o cual es el ciclo de cada una desde el desarrollo hasta la publicación y uso en el cliente lo que no comprendo muy bien.

Ojala me ayuden a aclarar esto y tambien le sirva de conocimiento a alguien mas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para entender esto, primero hay que entender que los navegadores siempre compilan los archivos de Javascript a un binario que ellos puedan entender.

Cuando se habla de compilar nuestro proyecto de Angular, no hablamos de esta compilación. Ésta la hace el navegador (Chrome, Firefox, etc) con respecto a sus binarios.

---

Ahora bien, con Angular (no AngularJS), la gran mayoría del desarrollo se realiza en TypeScript. Este código en TypeScript debe ser compilado a Javascript en algún momento. A esa compilación nos referimos.

Como dice [la documentación](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler), Angular ofrece dos maneras de compilar la aplicación:

> JIT (Justo en el momento), que compila la aplicación **en el navegador**
>   en momento de ejecución. Compilación JIT es la predeterminada cuando corres los comando de solo construcción o de construir y servir:
>
> ```
> ng build
> ng serve
> ```
>
> AOT (Antes del momento), que compila la aplicación **en el momento de
>   construcción** (compilación). Para compilar de manera AOT, agrega el sufijo `---aot` a los comandos de construcción:
>
> ```
> ng build --aot
> ng serve --aot
> ```

*Nota que cuando corres los comandos con `--prod` se compila con AOT por defecto.*

Todo esto significa que JIT y AOT son solo los momentos en los que vas a compilar el TypeScript a Javascript. Pero también hay ventajas y desventajas.

Cuando compilas JIT en desarrollo te ahorras el tiempo de compilar todo ese TypeScript y lo dejas al momento de ejecución. Pero tenés que llevarte el compilador de Angular que pesa bastantito. Es mejor para hacer compilaciones rápidas en desarrollo.

Cuando compilas en AOT tu tiempo de compilación va a tardar mucho, pero te ahorras el espacio del compilador. Por lo que es mejor para producir el código de producción.

Comment: Justamente después de investigar mas llegue a una conclusión similar, básicamente el compilador de angular es el que marca la diferencia y era ahí donde estaba mi duda, ya que no entendía como el navegador podía compilar TS si se supone que no lo entiende, y ahora asumo que es por el compilador de angular, el mismo que mencionas en tu respuesta y que claro, pesa mas de lo conveniente.Gracias!!